# i have tried to do the problem on my own, but not getting any great results, also attaching my code with the problem

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In given integer array, if any integer is repeating then replace it with a number greater than that number which has not been inserted yet in the array.
Eg. 1, 3, 4, 5, 3       Output: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6

---

```
class duplicates{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input the size");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[]=new int[n];
   System.out.println("enter the elements of an array");
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[i]==arr[j])
        {
          arr[j]=arr[n-1]+48;
          n--;

        }
      }
    }
   System.out.println("array is" + Arrays.toString(arr));

  }
}
```

Comment: Show code as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: (1) After sorting, duplicates are direct neighbours of each other so the nested `for`s aren't necessary. (2) If multiple duplicates appear they are always replaced with the same number `arr[n-1]+48`

Comment: edited.... plz suggest some other logic for the problem, since above code is not working if there are same elements at the last indexes, i.e for eg, at n-2 & n-1 position

Comment: Introduce another variable, e.g. `newNumber` which should be initially one (or 48) more than greatest number. Each time you assign a new number to a duplicate, increase `newNumber`.

Comment: ya....!! got it... thank u...!!

Answer (score 0):

this will be the solution of above problem.

```
import java.util.*;
class duplicates {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input the size");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int arr[]=new int[n];
   System.out.println("enter the elements of an array");
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
   int nw = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[i]==arr[j])
        {
          arr[j]=arr[n-1]+nw;
          nw++;


        }
      }
    }
   System.out.println("array is" + Arrays.toString(arr));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Replace repeating elements with greater that greatest values
 * Input : arr = {1, 3, 4, 5, 3}
 * Output : 1 3 4 5 6
 * Explanation: Here 3 is repeating so it is replaced with 6
 */
public class ReplaceRepeatedElementWithGreaterValue {
    //returns the maximum element
    static int max_element(int arr[]) {
        int max = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (max < arr[i])
                max = arr[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    static void replaceElements(int arr[], int n) {
        // Maximum element in an array
        int maxx = max_element(arr);
        List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // check whether the element is
            // repeated or not
            if (!s.contains(arr[i])) {
                s.add(arr[i]);
            } else {
                // update the repeated element with the
                // maxx element
                arr[i] = maxx + 1;
                maxx++; // update the max
                // mark the maximum element as visited
                s.add(maxx);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the size of the input array:");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        System.out.println("enter the elements of an array:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        replaceElements(arr, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```